# Mongoose Add New Field To Collection (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  admin: Boolean,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
```

Let's assume I have made 100 `Users` using this schema.

Now I want to change the schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  admin: Boolean,
  created_at: Date,
  friends: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], //the new addition
  updated_at: Date
});
```

I need all new `Users` to have this field. I also want all of the 100 existing `Users` to now have this field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mongoose [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) to update all your documents in the collection.

```
User.update({}, { friends: [] }, { multi: true }, function (err, raw) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
});
```

I don't recommend to do it in production if the collection is big, since it is a heavy operation. But in your case it should be fine.

Comment: What would I do in production then?

Comment: This is something you want to do only once?

If so, using a MongoDB shell script could be a better option.

Comment: I would only do this occasionally. Typically not often, just whenever I want to update the Model

Answer (score 1):

Using the query interface in a client app or your terminal you could do:

```
db.users.updateMany({ 
  $set: { "friends" : [] } 
});
```

Here's the [docs reference.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work for me :x

Here is my code

```
let test = await this.client.db.users.updateMany({
    $set: { "roles" : [] }
});
```

and the output

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

I don't know how to do, i tried a lot of things and uh it doesn't work :'(

EDIT: I found, here is my code

```
await this.client.db.users.updateMany({ }, [ {$set : { "roles": []} } ]);
```